# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(\frac{1}{n!})\, \cos(\frac{1}{n!}) $ And $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin(\frac{1}{n!})}{\cos(\frac {1}{n!})} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series converge because I've proceed like this and got that series convergent but I'm not sure.
Let the series be $S$
\begin{align*} 
S &= \sin(\frac{1}{n!})\, \cos(\frac{1}{n!}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \sin(\frac{2}{n!}) \\
\end{align*}

and we know that $ -1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1 $

$\frac{-1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}\,\sin(\frac{2}{n!}) \leq \frac{1}{2} $

My solution is correct ?

But for second one I'm not getting any intuition to proceed further. Please help me.

Thank you !!

Comment: Does what series converge? Are you taking the sum $\sum_{n\ge 1} \sin \frac1{n!} \cos \frac1{n!}$? If so, knowing that each term is between $-\frac12$ and $\frac12$ is not enough.

Comment: @MishaLavrov yeah let me edit the question, so how to say about convergence or divergence of the series ??

Comment: **Hint :** $$\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)\, \cos\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right) \right|\leq \dfrac{1}{n!}$$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe means convergent ?? Because $\frac{1}{n!} $ is convergent 

Comment: For the second, you could use that if $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{4}$ then $0 < \tan \theta < \theta$.

Comment: Try the limit comparison test with $\frac1{n!}$.

Comment: @aschepler Did you instead mean $0 < \tan\theta < 2\theta$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oops, I made a thought error. So I did mean it, but was wrong; yours is correct.